Coil AsyncImage not loading https image URL in JetPack Compose Android
I am using AsyncImage to load a public URL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1025.png". It's not loading the image but occupying the space and showing a blank white screen.
It's working well for all other URLs that are available over internet. When I tried to download the same image and host it is some server I got the url as "https://i.ibb.co/DG0GRmB/1.png". which is working fine. That implies there is no issue with code but with the URL.
when I tried to put the non-working URL in the chrome of emulator it is showing the ssl certifate is not verified. I feel this is the issue. how to resolve it.
Below is the code snippet which I have been using for fetching the Image.
AsyncImage(model = "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/PokeAPI/sprites/master/sprites/pokemon/1025.png",
)

I am also using internet permission in manifest So, it won't be an issue.
